# Can I track 70 pressure sensors from Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, pressure

I am a beginner at Arduino which I just received in the mail. My understanding is my Arduino Mega has 54 digital inputs and 16 analog inputs making for 70 inputs all together. I would like to track pressure sensors which are configured to detect simply open or closed. Given I can use my analog inputs as digital inputs can I have 70 pressure sensors? My project differs from others in that I dont need to track a gradation. In regards to the mega wiring what can I do to achieve this? Will I need a separate breadboard for each pressure sensor?

Comment: It depends on what your pressure sensors are.

Comment: I am building my pressure sensors from velostat and copper tape. How about for arguments sake we say I am using something out of the box that is either simply open or closed. I can adapt the sensor to meet my needs. Hypothetically can I connect all the sensors to digital inputs?

Comment: Yes. The sensors are just buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the commentary. In my literature i see a complex wiring scheme for a button. Can you tell me the wiring scheme?

Comment: IO pin to button. Button to GND. Turn on internal pullup. Nothing can be simpler.

Comment: `In my literature i see a complex wiring scheme for a button.` ... please share the literature if you can

Comment: how are the sensors arranged? .... what is the distance between the sensors? ... are they in any kind of groups? .... you could use a `matrix keypad` arrangement of 8x10, for example. ... then you would only require 7 connections to the arduino

Comment: also be aware, that you would need some I/O pins to "present" whatever you get from those sensors. And that probably 2 of that 70 I/O pins would be connected to your computer, while programming/debugging your code (you can output the results there as well, but you may want to send the results out in other way, say I2C (so more 2 I/O pins) to manipulate something to beep or blink or so, when some sensors are pressed.). Should I need to read exactly 70 inputs (or even more) for just 0/1, I would use some shift-registers for all inputs and poll them with just 3 pins, having rest free for outputs